# List comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have some trouble with list comprehension, I think I already know how to use it well but certainly I don't.
So here is my code:

```
vector1=[x for x in range(0,351,10)]
first=list(range(0,91))
second=list(range(100,181))
third=list(range(190,271))
fourth=list(range(280,351))
Quadrants=first+second+third+fourth
string=['First']*91+['Second']*81+['Third']*81+['Fourth']*71

vector2=dict(zip(Quadrants,string))
Quadrant=[]

for n in range (len(vector1)):

    Quadrant+=[vector2[vector1[n])]]
```

So i want to do the `for_loop` with list comprehension, but i can't... I tried this:

```
Quadrant=[y3 for y3 in [vector2[vector1[i]]] for i in range (len(vector1))]
```

Comment: don't you want to be using `361` in your `range()` calls instead of `351`? There are 360 degrees in a circle...

Comment: @MattDMo but then you'd get 37 10 degree slices. OP's is correct (360 degrees IS 0 degrees, the start of the range)

Comment: @user3424423 Where? I think not.

Comment: @Adam, oh I see. I was skipping the 0th index :)

Comment: This is a bad application of a list comp, OP. Keep it the way you have it -- it's perfect :)

Comment: @ThenewbieOne Indeed, I'm sorry.

Comment: For your first list comprehension, what are you expecting `[x for x in range(0,351,10)]` to give you besides `range(0,351,10)` itself (in 2.x) or `list(range(0,351,10))` (in 3.x)? Any list comprehension with nothing in the expression, only one `for`, and no `if` is useless.

Comment: @AdamSmith Oh i thought there was a form! Indeed Thanks!:)

Comment: @abarnert, not accurate, e.g. `[x[1] for x in blah]`. no `if`, still useful.

Comment: @acushner but then there's something in the expression! Item access is still an expression :P

Comment: @abarnert I'm in 3.x . So I get it, better keep the for_loop intead of maiking it a list comp. :). But i just want to learn how to use the list comp properlly...

Comment: @AdamSmith well `x` is still an expression... but i see what you're saying.

Comment: @ThenewbieOne: No, you're not getting it at all. To make a list out of something that isn't a list, just call `list(range(0,351,1))`; there's no need for either an explicit `for` statement or a list comprehension there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you're trying to convert to a listcomp:

```
Quadrant=[]    
for n in range (len(vector1)):
    Quadrant+=[y[vector1[n]]]
```

First, you have to convert that into a form using `append`. There's really no reason to build a 1-element list out of `y[vector1[n]]` in the first place, so just scrap that and we have something we can `append`directly:

```
Quadrant=[]
for n in range(len(vector1)):
    Quadrant.append(y[vector1[n]])
```

And now, we have something we can convert directly into a list comprehension:

```
Quadrant = [y[vector1[n]] for n in range(len(vector1))]
```

That's all there is to it.

However, I'm not sure why you're doing `for n in range(len(vector1))` in the first place if the only thing you need `n` for is `vector1[n]`. Just loop over `vector1` directly:

```
Quadrant=[]
for value in vector1:
    Quadrant.append(y[value])
```

Which, again, can be converted directly:

```
Quadrant = [y[value] for value in vector1]
```

However, all of this assumes that your original explicit loop is correct in the first place, which obviously it isn't. Your `vector1` is a *dict*, not a list. Looping over it the keys from 0 to `len(vector1)` is just going to raise `KeyError`s all over the place. Changing it to loop directly over `vector1` is going to solve that problem, but it means you're looping over the keys. So… I have no idea what your code was actually trying to do, but get the simple but verbose version right first, and you can probably convert it to a comprehension just as easily as the above.

Comment: Well `vector1` is a list, `vector2`is a _dict_

Comment: @ThenewbieOne: You edited your code after my answer, renaming `vector1` to `vector2` and `y` to `vector1` or something like that. I'm not sure why you did that, but presumably you can apply the same renaming to my code.

Comment: @well actually `y==vector2` but copying the code back to here I miss that. Sorry for that

Comment: BTW. Thank you so much for the explanation! The answer is pretty right. And now i feel quite dumb xD. Thank you again